# How to loop data into textarea thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Do you know how can we loop data into textarea in thymeleaf?
Please you help to me a sample or any suggestion to do this.
Thanks.

1. java code

```
    @GetMapping("/import_billing")
    public String getImportBilling(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("importBilling", new ImportBilling());
        return "importBilling";
    }

    @PostMapping("/import_billing")
    public String postImportBilling(ImportBilling request, Model model, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
                System.out.println(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            model.addAttribute("importBilling", request);
            return "importBilling";
        }
        ApiResponse response = cardHolderService.importBillingData(request);
        model.addAttribute("response", response.getData());
        return "importBilling";
    }
```

1. Html code

```
<div class="container-fluid" layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="page-information" th:action="@{/import_billing}" th:object="${importBilling}"
                      method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="number"           
                                   th:value="*{from}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="number"
                                   th:value="*{to}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                <i id="_spinner">Execute</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Output console</label>
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="chart-area">
                <div class="form-group" th:each="temp:*{response}" >
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"  th:text="${temp}"/>></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, after on click button **Execute** I would like all response display in **textarea**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `th:inline="text"` and write your loop using [textual syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#textual-syntax).  For example, instead of:

```
<div class="form-group" th:each="temp:*{response}" >
  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"  th:text="${temp}"/>></textarea>
</div>
```

Do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" th:inline="text">
    [# th:each="temp: *{response}"]
      [[${temp}]]
    [/]
  </textarea>
</div>
```